# Refused to display facebook.com/xti.php in a frame because it set X-Frame-options to sameorigin

Tags: facebook, sdk, frame

I only get an error in the google chrome console. I tried with edge and I don't have this error.

I'm trying to figure out which is causes this error.

I receive this error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/xti.php?xt=[...]' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

There are alot of characters between [].
I'm wondering if facebook sdk can cause that. Anyone want else has already faces this error?

Edit: I get this error when I add the facebook page plugin. Everythings works, but I want to know why I get this error.

The error appear when I tabbed out then I come back to the website.

Thanks

Comment: Im running into the same issue. Looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue came up while implementing facebook's customer chat plugin. See [here in troubleshooting  tip #1 at page end](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/). It was because the domain you want to display it on hasn't been whitelisted. That was the case almost all the time an error like this came up.

You can connect the dots and find out how it could apply to your application. Although, 'same origin' makes me think it could be related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which could be the underlying cause of this whole scenario in the first place.